# Is there a way to get geolocation data manually for testing?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

Is there a way to het geolocation of Chrome of Firefox web browser manually so that I can test my web app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Firefox: [Geolocater](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/geolocater/)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this'll help - I've just released a [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mfodligkojepnddfhkbkodbamcagfhlo) to do just that. It's not 100% full-proof, but it should do the trick for most cases.